# How to setup iredmail or dovecot with ssl ubuntu?

Tags: server, email, webserver, mail-server

How to setup iredmail or dovecot with ssl ubuntu?

i want to create emails and connect them to lampp server

Answer (score 1):

as the first your domain must have MX record. MX record is domain name, not IP address. This is for mail delivering to your domain (incoming emails).

Your question is too general, try to follow this tutorial:

https://docs.iredmail.org/install.iredmail.on.debian.ubuntu.html